# The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'syscolumns', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'

Tags: sql-server-2005

**MSSQL 2005 sp3 32 bit running on Windows 2003**

I have a sql server user MyUser in a database called MyDatabase.  MyUser is able to access the MyDatabase database via SSMS.  He is also dbo for that database.

When using the EMS Database Comparer 2011 to compare this database, I am getting the following error.

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'syscolumns', database
>   'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'

MyUser is not in the db_denydatareader or db_denydatawriter database roles

Is this normal, if so, what can be done to resolve it.

I am able to run the comparison as sysadmin.

I ran a trace using profiler and replayed using the MyUser user

Here is the result

**The Query that causes the error**

```
SELECT
    p.action
,   p.protecttype
,   p.columns
,   p.grantor
,   MAX(c.colid) AS colnum
,   u.name 
FROM
    sysprotects p 
    INNER JOIN 
        sysusers u 
        ON u.uid = p.uid 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        syscolumns c 
        ON c.id = p.id 
WHERE 
    p.id = 1497772393  
GROUP BY 
    p.id
,   p.action
,   p.protecttype
,   p.columns
,   p.grantor
,   u.name
```

**The error sent back by profiler**

> [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]The SELECT permission was
>   denied on the object 'syscolumns', database 'mssqlsystemresource',
>   schema 'sys'. (State 42000) (Code 229)

**Some additional Clues**

1. Permissions error if the query is run from SSMS on the same machine as EMS
2. No error when if the query is run from SSMS on the MSSQL server itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error indicates the login does not have `SELECT` permissions on the `sys` schema. This would require you to specifically grant `SELECT` to the login, or I believe you could also just `GRANT VIEW DEFINITION` for the database.

**Update**
Sorry just caught that last sentence. I have not worked with that software but seems it might be using a different login to execute the query if you can execute the same query fine in SSMS.

On a side note, since you are in SQL 2005, it would be a better practice to start using the [new views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187376%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) for looking at catalog information.

Comment: Actually, I just ran the query from SSMS on the same machine that has EMS and I am now seeing the same error.  So the GRANT DEFINITION and granting SELECT to sys for MyUser has not resolved the problem.   Maybe there isn't a way to manually grant access to the syscolumns table in mssqlsystemresource?

Comment: USE myDatabase;
GRANT SELECT ON syscolumns TO [MyUser];

Comment: Shawn, that was the right answer, I had to GRANT SELECT on every table that was analyzed by EMS.  That meant syscolumns, sysusers, sysprotects, sysindexkeys, sysreferences.  I am still getting an error but this time its EMS that's sending back an access violation.  Since the people running the comparisons are on a distant untrusted network are there any other options?

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow your user access to the objects contained in the 'sys' schema.  The dbo database role allows a user to view and change all the contents in a database under the 'dbo' schema(as the owner).

Reference:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387.aspx

Comment: I have already granted SELECT to the sys schema to MyUser and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: What server role does your user have?  Public?

Comment: Yes just Public

Answer (score 0):

Which [SQL server principal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms181127%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) is EMS Database Comparer 2011 using to connect to your database? This account is the one that needs the appropriate permissions. You can use profiler to see the account that is trying to connect to the DB. For meta data visibility permissions check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190785%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the response, I actually already did use Profiler to review the queries being used by EMS.  The server principal now has the right to access the tables from mssqlsystemresource.  But I am getting another error from MSComparer.exe